# How relying on this.props in calculating new state may broke my React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

The React documentation tells a lot about that `setState()` is async and consequences of this trait. 
In particular, [it says](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

And it also provides good examples why relying on `this.props` may (and will) broke your code. One of them (from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)):

```
// multiple call like this
this.setState({ quantity: state.quantity + 1 });

// may be batched and will result in the equivalent of
Object.assign(
    previousState,
    { quantity: state.quantity + 1 },
    { quantity: state.quantity + 1 },
    ...
 );
```

The examples are very illustrative and helpful during understanding the async nature of state update.

Unfortunately I cannot find any similar examples about relying on `this.props` in state updating. 
 
Can someone help me with that? I would like to see minimal illustrative code, but if you have a huge real-life example it will be great too. :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function as first argument to `setState`. This function gets the state and props as arguments, and the object you return from this function will be used to update the state.

**Example**

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({ counter: state.counter + props.step }))
```

One way to see that this is important is when you invoke a function in a child component that might result in the parent component changing the props given to the child. If you refer to `this.props` you will get an outdated value.

**Example**

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  onClick = () => {
    this.props.onIncrement();

    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + this.props.step });
    // This works
    // this.setState((state, props) => ({ counter: state.counter + props.step }));
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.onClick}>{this.state.counter}</button>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    step: 0
  };

  incrementStep = () => {
    this.setState(({ step }) => ({ step: step + 1 }));
  };

  render() {
    return <Counter step={this.state.step} onIncrement={this.incrementStep} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yep, I know about the right way. :) I would like to see an example *why it is bad to* do, e.g., `this.setState((state) => ({ counter: state.counter + this.props.step }))`.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting example! But I have edited `Counter#onClick()` to `this.setState((state) => ({ counter: state.counter + this.props.step }));` and it seems to be still working.

Comment: @Tholle , I used somewhat similar , but props turns to be undefined for me , when I pass function to setState props I receive are undefined ??